# How can I open an URL and access the elements in that URL?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. I want to write a code to open a url and access the elements in that url.
For example, open Google page using Window.open and click sign- in in that page.
Can anyone tell me how to make this out?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask]

Comment: Well JavaScript has same origin policy so it is not going to happen that easily.

Comment: You cant do that unless the website provide you with some sort of API

Comment: I think what you need is to write a browser extension.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can do it by using AJAX:

`$.get("URL_YOU_WANT_TO_ACCESS", function(data) {
    var $doc = $(data);
});`

Comment: Nope, not what the OP wants, they want to be able to control the other website, not access a copy of it

Comment: Yeah, you are right. If this is really what he needs, I think it is not possible.